# How to access the elements of single channel IplImage in Opencv

Tags: c++, c, opencv

How can I access the **Elements** of an **IplImage** (single channel and IPL_DEPTH_8U depth).

I want to change the pixel value at a particular (x, y) position of the image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

opencv provide CV_IMAGE_ELEM method to access elements of IplImage,it's a macro,

```
define CV_IMAGE_ELEM( image, elemtype, row, col )       \
    (((elemtype*)((image)->imageData + (image)->widthStep*(row)))[(col)])
```

second parameter is the type of

Comment: that's generally the correct approach, but i think that in this restricted case ( 8bit single channel ) it's worth using imageData bytes.

Answer (score 3):

Pixels are stored inside imageData array.
So, since your image is single channel you just have to do like:

```
myimage.imageData[y*myimage.width+x] = 100;
```

This ensure in imageData the right offset from beginning of buffer, and it's more readable than any other pointer algebra operation.

In N-channels images it's enough to multiply by N the array offset, and add the number of channel to read:

i.e. for an RGB image

```
myimage.imageData[3*(y*myimage.width+x)+0] = 100; //Red
myimage.imageData[3*(y*myimage.width+x)+1] = 100; //Green
myimage.imageData[3*(y*myimage.width+x)+2] = 100; //Blue
```

Any optimization to avoid to multiply data to obtain index can be done according to the goal you have to achieve.

Comment: I believe you should use -> rather than .

Comment: It depends on what myimage actually is, but generally.. you are right

Answer (score 2):

The fast way to get the pixel value is use macro.

```
CV_IMAGE_ELEM( image_header, elemtype, y, x_Nc )
```

And in your case, the Image is single channel.So you can get the i,j pixel value by

```
CV_IMAGE_ELEM(image, unsigned char, i, j)
```