# OpenCV - get grey value from an image

Tags: c++, c, image-processing, opencv, computer-vision

Hello everybody right now I'm trying to getting grey value for every pixel in an image
what I mean with grey value is the white or black level from an image let's say 0 for white and 1 for black. for an example for this image

[image]

the value I want will be like

```
 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 1 1 1 0 0
 0 0 1 1 0 0
 0 0 1 1 0 0
 0 0 1 1 0 0
 0 0 1 1 0 0
 0 0 1 1 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

is this possible? if yes how to do it with OpenCV in C? or if it's impossible with OpenCV is there any other library that can do this?

Comment: just use for loops and then cvGetReal2D (C API)..

Comment: is this an only-c question? Or you use c++, really, as the tags indicate?

Comment: @MizukiKai I already tried Get2D but I haven't tried GetReal2D,please wait I'll try, thank you

Comment: @BarnabasSzabolcs I prefered it in C,but if you have solution in other languange maybe I can try to understand it and try to use it in C or C++, and yes right now I'm using C++.thank you

Comment: both cvGet2D and cvGetReal2D will give same results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you ask is certainly possible but *how* it can be done depends on a lot of things. If you use C++, on SO we generally expect you to use the C++ interface which means you have a `cv::Mat` object and loaded the image with something like this: (using namespace cv)

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
Mat mat_gray = imread(path, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
```

or by

```
Mat mat = imread(path); // and assuming it was originally a color image...
Mat mat_gray;
cvtColor(mat, mat_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY); //...convert it to grayscale.
```

Now, if you just want to access pixel values one-by-one, you use `_Tp& mat.at<_Tp>(int x,int y);`. That is:

```
for(int x=0; x<mat_gray.rows; ++x)
  for(int y=0; y<mat_gray.cols; ++y)
    mat_gray.at<uchar>(x,y); // if mat.type == CV_8U
```

You can [look up your type here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13490111/1705967), which you should use in place of uchar if the mat.type is other than CV_8U.

As for the **pure C** interface, you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9697364/1705967). But if you use C++, you should definitely use the C++ interface.

Comment: I will try this tomorrow and report the result to you!thanks for the answer I'll surely accept the answer if it works :D

Comment: Cool, here is some additional help: [link to opencv docs on loading and displaying an image](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/display_image/display_image.html)