# Weird Values in an IplImage

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv

I do have an IplImage I. and it's supposed to have values from 0 to 255 (pixels).
I'm having in it unfortunately weird special characters like:

```
ØÕÖÕÓÎËÍÌÈÃÃÁ»¶±«¨¤Ÿ™”‰
```

I did the following:
uchar* d_I = (uchar*) I->imageData;

How can I convert those characters into values from 0 to 255 ?

Comment: How are you getting the values from the image and how are you printing them?

Comment: unsigned char stands for 8 bit values if you wannt to watch the values with the debugger you could just: int tmp = d_I[pos];

Answer (score 0):

Since you have tagged c++, here's how you can print a char as a number using cout.
Keep your previous code.

```
uchar* d_I = (uchar*) I->imageData;
std::cout <<(int) *d_I;
```

Comment: for c++ I would say the right style is std::cout <<static_cast<int>(*d_I);

Answer (score 0):

are you taking image->widthStep into account? the pixels aren't simply the pointer cast to the data type you passed to cvCreateImage (or what got loaded by cvLoadImage) then incremented... the rows are aligned to 4 or 8 bytes, so each row isn't necessarily touching in memory (though it would be close within a few bytes).

Access your pixels with:

(unsigned char)CV_IMAGE_ELEM(myImage, unsigned char, y, x)

or if you started with a 64F depth image:

(double)CV_IMAGE_ELEM(myImage, double, row, col)

see:
[How to access the elements of single channel IplImage in Opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679953/how-to-access-the-elements-of-single-channel-iplimage-in-opencv)

Answer (score -1):

Instead of casting in uchar, you should cast to int:

```
int* d_l = (int*)l->imageData
```

Comment: This is valid only if the depth of the IplImage is `CV_32S`. I don't think that the image in OP's problem has `CV_32S` depth. Its depth is `CV_8U` that's why it is mentioned that the values are in the range `0 - 255`.

Comment: @Turgal MY depth is 8U. So does that apply?

Comment: Unhandled exception at 0x00aa73c7 in ex4.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0d83dc30.

Comment: @user2187476... If the depth is `CV_8U`, then this approach will give you incorrect values. It will just read 4 pixels and interpret them as an `int`, which makes no sense. Please show the code where you are reading and displaying the values from the image.

Comment: And thus, suppose I was working with 8U, and the only Ipl that I will work on will be 32S, how can I convert the lat one. I will not go back again to change all my IplImages now to 8U!!!

Comment: @user2187476... If you want to read and write pixel values, the generic approach is to use `cvGet2D` and `cvSet2D`. These functions work on any type of image.

Comment: @user2187476 I did not get what you mean. As sgar91 said, you should show us a bit more of code like, what intern type is your image. Moreover, you tagg your question with 'c++', why don't you use the new version of opencv in c++ ?